# How to retrieve the value of a list variable when grouped by

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I am trying to group by a project ID so I can return a sum however when I try to return the value of a field using First() it only returns one value.

ASP.net c# project trying to return a sum for a field, I have the code returning the proper number using LINQ however I can't seem to return the corresponding string field. I have tried grouping by 2 fields but this returns too many records.

```
public class JobsByDrivetime
{
private string pid;
private double jobMinutes;
private string jobEventType;
public JobsByDrivetime(string pid, double jobMinutes,string jobEventType)
{
    this.pid = pid;
    this.jobMinutes = jobMinutes;
    this.jobEventType = jobEventType;

}

public string Pid
{
    get { return pid; }
    set { pid = value; }
}

public double JobMinutes
{
    get { return jobMinutes; }
    set { jobMinutes = value; }
}

public string JobEventType
{
    get { return jobEventType; }
    set { jobEventType = value; }
}
}

List<JobsByDrivetime> ProjectbyDrivetime = new List<JobsByDrivetime>();

ProjectbyDrivetime.Add(new JobsByDrivetime("0186975-0001", 439, "HR"));
ProjectbyDrivetime.Add(new JobsByDrivetime("0186975-0001", 100, "HR"));
ProjectbyDrivetime.Add(new JobsByDrivetime("0186975-0001", 180, "JR"));

var projectBydrivetimeList = ProjectbyDrivetime
.GroupBy(v => v.Pid) //(c => new { Pid = c.Pid, ProjectType = c.JobEventType })
.Select(g => new
{
    Pid = g.Key,
    ProjectMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.JobMinutes),
    ProjectType=g.Select(x=> x.JobEventType).First()
}).ToList();
foreach (var D in projectBydrivetimeList)
{
    shiftSummary.Add("<tr><td>" + D.Pid + "</td><td>" + D.ProjectType + "</td><td>" + D.ProjectMinutes + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Output

0186975-0001 HR 539

0186975-0001  HR 180

It is grouping the ProjectMinutes correctly(by Project Type) but it is displaying only one of the 2 project types. I expect D.ProjectType to be HR on the first and JR on the second. I get that it's because I am using First().

Comment: It would be great if you could share sample input/output.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, please show data

Comment: I added data and output, anything else to clarify?

Comment: @DougFarrell so you want to group by Project ID and then retrive everything of firs group ? Sorry, didnt understand the whole intention ?

Comment: Yes, group by projectID, sum all the ProjectMinutes  for the different ProjectType's with the same projectID.

Comment: I thought ProjectType=g.Select(x=> x.JobEventType) and then calling D.ProjectType would have worked just fine but it generated an error which led me down this path. I tried to add it to the group as seen in the commented line //(c => new { Pid = c.Pid, ProjectType = c.JobEventType }) however this did not produce desired results either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your requirement correctly. You were pretty much on course by your thoughts to Group By both Pid and ProjectType.

```
var projectBydrivetimeList = ProjectbyDrivetime
                             .GroupBy(v => new {v.Pid,v.JobEventType}) 
                             .Select(g => new
                             {
                               Pid = g.Key.Pid,
                               ProjectMinutes = g.Sum(x => x.JobMinutes),
                               ProjectType=g.Select(x=> x.JobEventType).First()
                              }).ToList();
```

Sample Output

[image]

**Update**

Based on your comment, another Sample Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anu, I am getting the same results, however, when I tried that route. 0186975-0001 HR 479 
0186975-0001 JR 60 
0186975-0001  HR 180. It doesn't seem to be combining the 2 HR's?? The data is different however the results are the same, not combining hr's. :(

Comment: @DougFarrell Could you check the answer, I have updated it with your new input. Result seems to combining the HR values. Did you end with a whitespace somewhere in your "HR " string ?

Comment: The actual data in the list is: 0186975-0001 HR 60 
0186975-0001 JR 60 
0186975-0001  HR 180 
0186975-0001 HR 419

Comment: @DougFarrell The answer has been updated with your new List. Kindly check the update section

Comment: I will look but all data is entered via drop downs

Comment: No white space in the HR string, white space in the projectID string found!! Thank you so much for your time Anu!